# How can I create a dynamic matrix structure using only pointers?

Tags: c

I'm doing a program where I can only use pointers, that is, I have to load a text file with a letter soup without using arrays. Each letter of this soup has 8 pointers around it that point to the neighboring letters.

I already have a code structure made but I can not do more from here.

Can anyone help?

```
typedef struct letter           ///estrutura para cada letra da sopa
{
  char *lname;
  struct letter *Norte;
  struct letter *Sul;
  struct letter *Este;
  struct letter *Oeste;
  struct letter *Nordeste;
  struct letter *Sudeste;
  struct letter *Sudoeste;
  struct letter *Noroeste;
  struct letter *pnext;
} LETTER;

typedef struct soup         ///estrutura para a sopa de letras
{
  int lin;
  int col;
  LETTER *pfirst;
} SOUP;

void read_soup_txt(SOUP *pcs, char *fn, int lin, int col) {
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(fn, "r");
  char c;
  if (fp != NULL) {
    pcs->lin = lin;
    pcs->col = col;
    LETTER *current = malloc(sizeof(LETTER)), *previous;
    pcs->pfirst = current;

    for (int i = 0; i < pcs->lin; i++)     ///linhas
        {
      for (int j = 0; i < pcs->col; j++)     ///colunas
          {
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);                     ///le o char
        current->lname = malloc(sizeof(char));       ///aloca espaço para o char
        strcpy(current->lname, &c);             ///copia o char para a estrutura
        previous = current;

        if (i == 0 && j == 0)           ///letra canto superior esquerdo
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < pcs->col - 1)     ///primeira linha
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i == 0 && j == pcs->col - 1)      ///letra do canto superior direito
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i > 0 && i < pcs->lin && j == 0)     ///letras na coluna da esquerda
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i == pcs->lin - 1 && j == 0)     ///letra do canto inferior esquerdo
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i == pcs->lin - 1 && j > 0 && j < pcs->col - 1)      ///ultima linha
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i == pcs->lin - 1 && j == pcs->col - 1) ///letra do canto inferior direito
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i > 0 && i < pcs->lin - 1 && j == pcs->col - 1) ///letras da coluna direita
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        if (i > 0 && i < pcs->lin - 1 && j > 0 && j < pcs->col - 1) ///letras do meio do tabuleiro
            {
          current->Norte = NULL;
          current->Sul = NULL;
          current->Este = NULL;
          current->Oeste = NULL;
          current->Noroeste = NULL;
          current->Nordeste = NULL;
          current->Sudeste = NULL;
          current->Sudoeste = NULL;
        }

        previous->pnext = current;
      }

    }
  } else
    printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo!");
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Notice that a pointer can often be viewed as an array (and arrays are decaying into pointers). You could heap-allocate an array using  `calloc` and then put than in a pointer. Your question is really unclear.

Comment: `char c;  ...   strcpy(current->lname, &c);`  is a problem. `strcpy(d,s)` expects `s` to point to a _string_. ("A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character.")  `&c` does not point to a _string_, just to  1 character.

Comment: Can you use temporary 2d arrays? I think it would be simpler to first read the data into a 2d array, then link up your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to read all the letters to your struct then you fill the pointers